# Multilanguage htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, multilingual

I have a simple php site, which i am looking to make multi-language. My goal is to have seperate xml files holding the translations and using a function to fetch the phrases corresponding to the language of the site.

Each site has a different domain, but will use the same database and the same php files (which are deployed to each domain on one or more web servers).

However, I want the URLs to be language specific. So if i have a URL /lineups in english i want to have a danish one saying /startopstillinger

What is the best way to do this? To manually make htaccess for each site or is it possible to make rules based on the domain name in a single htaccess file?

Hope someone can shed a little light for me.

Rgds
Rasmus

Comment: Personally i would handle this in a db and let php create the page. leave htaccess out of it. it will be more manageable

Comment: While I agree with the comment above _(this is better suited for a database)_, Do you have the translated urls mapped in an xml file?
If you **really** wanted to use _.htaccess_ files, you should generate them automatically.  Please post any url mapping samples or code you have so far _(if any)_.

Comment: I actually do not have any code yet, as i am still planning this. My issue is however, that I am looking to have ten different domains with ten different languages so more or less all rules i have in my current htaccess will have to have rules for each site. Is it possible to have any if statements in a htaccess file?